# In SystemVerilog Is it possible to place a generate block in a static function?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm using a virtual class + static function to implement parameterized functions in SystemVerilog. This works well. However, I'm now trying to make the function implementation conditional on the parameter values. For example:

```
virtual class C#(integer A);
    static function logic func(input a, input b);
        generate
            if (A == 1) begin
                return a & b;
            end
            else if (A == 2) begin
                return a ^ b;
            end
            else begin
                $error("Invalid parameter value.");
            end
        endgenerate
    endfunction
endclass
```

QuestaSim complains with "near "generate": syntax error, unexpected generate."

Is this illegal syntax? Is there any way to achieve the functionality above?

Please note that this is a contrived example, as I can't share the actual code I'm using, but it should illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a `generate` construct inside a class definition. But in your example, there is no need to. You can simply remove the `generate/endgenerate` keywords and the generate-if becomes a procedural-if.

Comment: Does the procedural-if have a runtime cost? I'd like this to resolve to `a&b` or `a^b` or `$error...` at synthesis time.

Comment: Classes can't be synthesized.  They are only for testbench.

Comment: @Mikef not true. A virtual class + static function as used in my example is synthesizable.

Comment: I'm trying to track down exactly where this is stated in the spec. The technique is described in "13.8 Parameterized tasks and functions", though I'm not seeing where it's stated that it's synthesizable. I suppose it's possible I'm mistaken, but Vivado synthesizes this just fine.

Comment: It's also described in 5.6.7 of Sutherland's "[Synthesizing SystemVerilog](https://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2013-SNUG-SV_Synthesizable-SystemVerilog_paper.pdf)" paper. Again, I don't see it explicitly stated that this is synthesizable, but given the title and purpose of the paper, I believe that's what Sutherland is saying, which is consistent with my understanding of it.

Comment: @MattHusz. A good simulation tool propagates constant expressions finding dead code branches and optimizes them away. .

Comment: @Mikef, MattHusz; the original question did not originally say anything about needed to be synthesizable . However, parameterizable virtual classes with static methods were intended to be synthesizable so that SystemVerilog did not need to add a separate parameterizable function feature.

Comment: @dave_59, thanks although I'm concerned with synthesis much more than simulation (sorry, I could have been clearer in my original question). Does this procedural-if have a runtime cost, or will the synthesis tool just swap in the correct branch as is done in generate blocks?

Comment: @MattHusz A good simulation _or synthesis_ tool propagates constant expressions finding dead code branches and optimizes them away.

Answer (score 1):

This chart supports the @dave_59 answer.

[image]

Posting it because its supports the answer and have have found it useful more than once.
Source:

[what-goes-where-in-systemverilog](https://www.amiq.com/consulting/2014/10/01/what-goes-where-in-systemverilog/)